# How can I monitor the bulk API limit?

Tags: governorlimits, bulk-api, monitoring

Salesforce limits you to 10,000 batches per 24-hour period.

For reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_bulkapi.htm

Is there some kind of email alerting within Salesforce I can use to be alerted if my org is approaching this limit? Or if not, is there some API I can access containing my current usage so I can build something custom?

I am aware of the Org Health App, but this just creates a page with all of the information on it. I am needing to use this data external from Salesforce and would like some way where I can either query it or report on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call the Limits API with a GET request:

> GET /services/data/v45.0/limits

Your response map will include

```
  "DailyBulkApiRequests" : {
    "Max" : 10000,
    "Remaining" : 10000,
  }
```

as well as a breakdown by application.

Comment: DailyBulkApiBatches (API version 49.0 and later) or DailyBulkApiRequests (API version 48.0 and earlier)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current limits and usage by calling the REST API at `/services/data/vXX.X/limits` ([Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_limits.htm)). There is an API Usage Notification option, but that only applies to the API rate limits, not Bulk API usage.

Comment: lol, i just posted a comment since  i did not see any answer and wasn't sure.